# How to build recent Clang RPMs for Red Hat 7?

Tags: clang, llvm

I need to provide recent versions of Clang (5, 6 or 7 for test) to developers teams working on RH7.x boxes (today they are using the EPEL release 3.4.2)

I would like to build same packages as the EPEL ones: 
(And the ability to change the RPM release if I need to rebuild them)

- `clang-devel-6.0.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`
- `clang-6.0.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`
- `llvm-6.0.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`
- `llvm-libs-6.0.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`
- ...

What is the best way to do that?

**Where I am:**
I follow build instructions here: https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

Then I tried: `cpack -G RPM` with various options (`-DCPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE=1`) but result is always the same, I have one 'big' RPM like `LLVM-7.0.0svn-Linux.rpm`

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you'll need to modify the source package [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/clang-devel-3.4.2-9.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) to use the correct checkout of LLVM/Clang and update the included patches if necessary.